# UIButton setTitleColor UIControlState.selected not working

Tags: ios

Swift 3, Xcode 8, iOS 10.2

```
Colorbutton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.selected)
Colorbutton.setTitle("Selected", for: UIControlState.selected)
```

Do you know, why is this not working?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? _What_ isn't working?

Comment: Do you see the change if you add `Colorbutton.isSelected = true` ?

Comment: Yes... that is strange. That makes me curious to what .selected is actually used for, as @blyabtroi correctly notes from the documentation - This state has no effect.

Comment: All Controls share `UIControlState` , but only some Controls - such as `UISegmented​Control` - *do* have specific `Selected` states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the description of .Selected state:

> Selected state of a control. For many controls, this state has no
>   effect on behavior or appearance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Colorbutton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .selected)
```

Comment: So this doesn't have an effect on a UIButton, even though a UIButton can be in a `.selected` state? Weird......